# Отображение переменных в QtCreator через gdb

Tags: c++, qtcreator, gdb

Отладчик gdb не показывает содержимое переменной типа `std::string`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом если смотреть через gdb в консоле то он все показывает:

```
 milai@milai:~/projects/test_project/build/bin$ gdb ./test_project 
 GNU gdb (Ubuntu 9.1-0ubuntu1) 9.1
 Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
 License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
 This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
 There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
 Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
 This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
 Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
 For bug reporting instructions, please see:
 <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
 Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
     <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.

 For help, type "help".
 Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
 Reading symbols from ./test_project...
 (gdb) list
 1  #include <string>
 2  #include <iostream>
 3  
 4  int main(int argc, char* argv[])
 5  {
 6      const std::string str = "abc";
 7      std::cout << str << std::endl;
 8      return 0;
 9  }
 (gdb) b 7
 Breakpoint 1 at 0x12bb: file /home/milai/projects/test_project/main.cpp, line 7.
 (gdb) r
 Starting program: /home/milai/projects/test_project/build/bin/test_project 

 Breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdec8) at /home/milai/projects/test_project/main.cpp:7
 7      std::cout << str << std::endl;
 (gdb) info locals 
 str = "abc"
 (gdb) c
 Continuing.
 abc
 [Inferior 1 (process 40257) exited normally]
 (gdb) quit
 milai@milai:~/projects/test_project/build/bin$
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Окружение:

- Ubuntu 20.04.1
- qtcreator: 4.11.0
- gdb: 9.1
- g++ 9.3.0

Comment: брейк у тебя в gdb стоит на 7-й строке, а в креаторе на 8-й... вполне возможно, что к этому времени строка просто уничтожается...

Comment: @Fat-Zer как она может уничтожится если еще зона видимости не была покинута? Оптимизация не включена, флаг `-g` есть

Comment: @Rikitikitavi это же C++, тут и не такие странные вещи происходят.

Comment: да, могу воспроизвести на [таком комплекте](https://dpaste.com/H7VM8VY9M)... подтверждаю, что не работает... похож проблема именно с stl'евскими типами... больше всего похоже на баг где-то на стороне креатора... скорей всего это связано с тем, что они по-разному обрабатываются: голый gdb для их печати использует pretty-printers, что идут в комплекте с gcc, а qt-creator сам пытается их распарсить... возможно, он как-то неверно их интерпретирует...

Comment: @Rikitikitavi  В настройках QtCreator (меню Tools->options, потом "вкладка Debug") есть такая галочка "Load system gdb pretty printers". Попробуйте ее установить, должно завестись.

Comment: @KoVadim Да, это помогло.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По умолчанию, QtCreator не загружает скрипты от gdb, которые позволяют "красиво выводить сложные типы", но это можно включить в настройках.

Меню Tools->options, потом "вкладка Debug" есть такая галочка "Load system gdb pretty printers".

Comment: Маленькая поправка: да, дело было в этой галочке, и по умолчанию она была включена, и помогло то, что я ее отключил. Типы из `std` стали отображаться, но со всеми внутренностями,  Видимо как сказал @Fat-Zer, в комментариях к вопросу, это какая то ошибка в QtCreator, которая не позволяет разобрать скрипты от gdb.

Comment: есть подозрение, что это связано с питоном. Эти скрипты обычно не нем пишутся. У меня такое было, но обновление QtCreator часто лечило проблему.